# docker-compose: publish multiple ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to publish 2 ports of a simple docker container to make some tests.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue.

My simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM bash:4 
RUN echo ok
```

Built using `docker build . -t essai`

My first version for the docker-compose.yml file, this one works:

```
version: '3'
services:
  essai:
    image: essai 
    ports:
      - 25432:5432
```

But when I try to publish a second port like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  essai:
    image: essai 
    ports:
      - 25022:22
      - 25432:5432
```

I get this strange error message:

> $ docker-compose up Creating network "sandbox_default" with the
>   default driver Creating sandbox_essai_1 ...  Creating sandbox_essai_1
>   ... error
>
> ERROR: for sandbox_essai_1  Cannot create container for service essai:
>   invalid port specification: "1501342"
>
> ERROR: for essai  Cannot create container for service essai: invalid
>   port specification: "1501342" ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing
>   up the project.

Where does it find the port `1501342`?

Funny thing is when I write my docker-compose like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  essai:
    image: essai 
    ports:
      - "25022:22"
      - 25432:5432
```

It works.

What's the magic with these double quotes and the port number coming out of nowhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#ports), the recommended way to specify port mapping is string declaration specially when a container port lower than 60.