# Docker complaining of strange port specification

Tags: docker

I'm working on creating an alpine postfix container, using https://www.iops.tech/blog/postfix-in-alpine-docker-container/. I figure as it's under a year old, it should be good. I set it up, with the only difference being it's done in docker-compose instead of the container directly. I did test it as written in the blog (running docker directly), and it seems to work. But when I do a `dc up -d postfix` using these configs:

```
  postfix:
    build:
      context: ./docker/postfix
    container_name: postfix
    ports:
      - 8025:25
    environment:
      - POSTFIX_SMTP_HELO_NAME=localhost
      - POSTFIX_MYORIGIN=localhost
      - POSTFIX_MYHOSTNAME=localhost
```

I get `for postfix  Cannot create container for service postfix: invalid port specification: "481525"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose: publish multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056854/docker-compose-publish-multiple-ports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ports specification to wrap the ports in quotes

```yaml
    ports:
      - "8025:25"
```

> When mapping ports in the `HOST:CONTAINER` format, you may experience erroneous results when using a container port lower than 60, because YAML parses numbers in the format `xx:yy` as a base-60 value. For this reason, we recommend always explicitly specifying your port mappings as strings.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-1

I recommend always wrapping literal values in quotes, to be explicit and to be consistent, to try and avoid these gotchas.

#### Full conversion

This is the command from the article

```bash
docker run \
        -d \
        --rm \
        --init \
        --env POSTFIX_SMTP_HELO_NAME=localhost \
        --env=POSTFIX_MYORIGIN=localhost \
        --env=POSTFIX_MYHOSTNAME=localhost \
        --name postfix-alpine \
        -p 8025:25 \
        postfix-alpine:latest
```

I would translate it to a `docker-compose.yml` like this:

<sup>(I haven't tested this)</sup>

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  postfix:
    image: postfix-alpine:latest
    container_name: postfix-alpine
    build:
      context: "./docker/postfix"
    ports:
      - "8025:25"
    environment:
      POSTFIX_SMTP_HELO_NAME: "localhost"
      POSTFIX_MYORIGIN: "localhost"
      POSTFIX_MYHOSTNAME: "localhost"
```